# How do I get react-leaflet or leaflet to dynamically change the name of the LayersControl.Overlay

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

In the following I have a snippet of code that I use to add LayerControls to my react-leaflet map.

Notice the name is set to a date string. This "vae" object changes asynchronously (fetched from web server periodically).

```
{vaes.map(function (vae, vae_idx) {
              return (
                <LayersControl.Overlay name={vae.date.toString()}>
                  <MyVaeView
                    vae={vae}
                    vae_idx={vae_idx}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    markerRadius={markerRadius}
                  />
                </LayersControl.Overlay>
              );
            })}
```

I expect the layer control name to change. However it doesnt it stays fixed at the first date that I set (07:31:00 in the following). The rendered custom react component "MyVaeView" does however reflect that updated vae object (with the proper date: 07:31:07 in the following)

[image]

The vae.date updates once per second, and I have at most 6 overlay layers. The layer control names should move in a 6 second rolling window.

[image]

How Can I get react-leaflet and leaflet to change the name of the LayersControl.Overlay?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `key` prop on your repeated element? Typically `<LayersControl.Overlay name={vae.date.toString()} key={vae.date.toString()}>`

Comment: @ghybs You da man!!!! That worked.

Answer (score 2):

When instantiating several components in a loop (typically when looping an array with `myArray.map(item => <MyComponent />);`, make sure to also specify the `key` special prop, with some kind of identifier for your items: `myArray.map(item => <MyComponent key={item.id} />);`

This is how React knows which items are which between re-renders, even if the items data have partially or totally changed.

Without an explicit `key`, React defaults to using the list index.

See also https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

In your case, this default behaviour is the cause of your issue: on 2nd render, your rolling mechanism makes your initially 1st item be replaced by a new one (typically by the 2nd item or the 7th, depending on how exactly you implemented your roll). But it still is on index 0 of the list, so React thinks it is the same item, possibly with some updated data. Being the same item, React does not repaint it (for performance optimization), but only updates its props (hence when check it, you get your correct child Layer on map).
Now this may be a little trickier, but the way React-Leaflet LayersControl.Overlay is implemented, it keeps the same name once instantiated, even if you change that name later on.

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/v3.2.1/packages/react-leaflet/src/LayersControl.tsx#L83 => no dependency on `name` prop

To force a name change, just make React realize that it is actually a brand new item, by specifying a `key` with value that reflects the new item. Then React will instantiate a new LayersControl.Overlay component instead of trying to re-use the initial one.

See also https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop for more explanations and examples on the `key` special prop for React component identification.

By the way, all decent Front-end libraries have a very similar key mechanism: Angular and Vue for instance use the same performance optimization, and require similarly a `key` attribute to make the distinction.

Comment: Good detail @ghybs TY.

Comment: Just read through some of what you wrote & linked.. it cleared up quite a bit.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically change the name of the Overlay while preserving the order of the items?

Comment: Yes there should be. Please feel free to open a new question with details of your specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was in [ghybs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108796/ghybs)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197754/how-do-i-get-react-leaflet-or-leaflet-to-dynamically-change-the-name-of-the-laye/69207310#comment122310591_69197754):

> Have you tried adding a `key` prop on your repeated element? Typically `<LayersControl.Overlay name={vae.date.toString()} key={vae.date.toString()}>`